# Why does Assembly x86 repeats loops 255 times without writing cx register?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
section .text
org 100h

start:

petla:
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, napis
    int 21h
loop petla
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
section .data
napis db "kap $"
```

Example code above, it will print "kap" exactly 255 times. Is it because 2^8 = 256? (0-255) But even if that's true, cx is a 16-bit register not 8-bit.
Help !

Comment: You haven't initialized `cx` - this program might do *anything*. [`loop`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Loop_Instructions) will loop until `cx` is zero. What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: I don't think you read my question. I'm looking for an answer why does this loop repeat EXACTLY 255 times.

Comment: Whatever loaded this program left cx = 000ffh when starts the program. In a windows dos console program, if you used debug with the .com program, cx would have been set to 0, and it would have looped 65536 times.

Comment: Seeing as you didn't load `cx`, it must have already held EXACTLY `00FFh`.

Comment: There is no point in this question. If you're interested in the initial state of the registers, then ask *that* question instead, and provide full information about your platform.

Comment: Otherwise, accept the obvious fact that it loops as many times as specified in CX and therefore CX must have the value FFh when your program starts. If you care at all, you could easily confirm that fact.

Answer (score 2):

I copy-pasted your code in EMU8086 and ran it. In my case, it runs 291 times **everytime**. I ran it several times, I opened and close several programs (even heavy ones, like VS2012 and VMPlayer), I restarted Windows 8 twice, and the program always runs 291 times. I even ran other assembler programs that ended with different values for CX. For some reason, CX is always 123h in your code. Interesting.

So, dear ogechukwukama, I can only believe it depends on hardware and software. With my computer configuration it runs 291 times, with your computer configuration it runs 255 times. You should try with a friend with a different computer configuration, just to see what he gets.

Next is the code I have been running. It's your same code, I just made it runnable for EMU8086:

```
.stack 100h
.data
napis db "kap $"   
.code
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax
petla:
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset napis
  int  21h
loop petla
  mov ax, 4c00h
  int 21h
```

We can also blame the compiler. I am using EMU8086, programs run inside this emulator. EMU8086 assigns some value to CX just before the program runs. Maybe with a different compiler the value for CX would be different.

Comment: plus for restarting windows twice :)

Comment: @AlexanderZhak He should have reinstalled it too! :)

Comment: It most certainly depends in the version of DOS.